# Python Mechanize Error When Selecting Form

Tags: python, python-2.7, mechanize

Code of website which I am tying to submit ::: [FORM PART OF WEBSIDE CODE](http://codepad.org/esv9X1Ns)

---

Error which occur when I am trying to select form

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "call.py", line 35, in <module>
    loginAccount()
  File "call.py", line 15, in loginAccount
    browser.select_form(nr = 0)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mechanize/_mechanize.py", line 499, in select_form
    global_form = self._factory.global_form
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mechanize/_html.py", line 544, in __getattr__
    self.forms()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mechanize/_html.py", line 557, in forms
    self._forms_factory.forms())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mechanize/_html.py", line 237, in forms
    _urlunparse=_rfc3986.urlunsplit,
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mechanize/_form.py", line 844, in ParseResponseEx
    _urlunparse=_urlunparse,
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mechanize/_form.py", line 981, in _ParseFileEx
    fp.feed(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mechanize/_form.py", line 760, in feed
    raise ParseError(exc)
mechanize._form.ParseError: expected name token at '<!\\\\])/g,"\\\\$1").rep'
```

---

Source code (I wrote comment like # ERROR OCCUR HERE) :

```
   browser = mechanize.Browser()
   browser.set_handle_robots(False)
   browser.set_handle_refresh(False)
   browser.open("https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLoginAuth")
   browser.select_form(nr = 0)
   browser.form['Email'] = "MYMAIL@gmail.com"
   browser.form['Passwd'] = "MYPASWORD"
   browser.submit() # Till the here, works fine. I can login.

   resp = browser.open("https://accounts.google.com/b/0/SmsAuthSettings?Setup=1")
   resp = resp.read()
   browser.select_form(nr = 0) # ERROR OCCUR HERE
```

---

When I delete browser.select_form(nr = 0), program works fine.
What should I do ?

Comment: The code works for me without any errors.

Comment: When I read your comment, I tried with different email, even I tried to change my account's language but still same for me. I think you couldn't login your account so it redirected you another link, the link has form so it didn't give you error.

Comment: Are you sure `resp` variable contains an actual HTML code you've provided?

Comment: Runs fine for me also

Comment: Hey can you check your code if its include something like this : http://codepad.org/c6a8hNGZ You can see that only if your everything works fine.

Comment: You should mark Prajnesh Kunder's response as the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use a more robust parser, 
e.g.
browser = mechanize.Browser(factory=mechanize.RobustFactory())

Check out this link for more help:
http://www.thecodingforums.com/threads/mechanize-select_form-issue.359575/